# How to embed html codings in python tkinter

Tags: python, html, tkinter, embed

Can anyone please help me how I can use html codings in python GUI?
Suppose I want to use html forms in my tkinter frame or geolocation map from html in my tkinter window..

Comment: [This question has all possible answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46571448/tkinter-and-a-html-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter and a html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46571448/tkinter-and-a-html-file)

Comment: Thank you that helped me but I am able to insert only links, headings, paragraphs, etc but I am not able to insert html forms in that, please help me...

Comment: Ok then, Go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48909932/12352891) answer