# Python: How to use tkinter to open various scripts (bokeh)?

Tags: python, tkinter, bokeh

I have a bokeh code that I open it with the terminal typing:

```
bokeh serve --show graph2d.py
```

how can I make a tkinter open this bokeh.py(graph2d.py)?
Please help with this, I dont find how to make it work.
this is the tkinter:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
import graph2d
"""import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import ttk"""

window = Tk()

window.title("Welcome to PokerScatter app")

"""
WINDOW_SIZE = "600x400"
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry(WINDOW_SIZE)
"""

selected = IntVar()

rad1 = Radiobutton(window,text='2d Scatter', value=1, variable=selected, command=graph2d)

rad2 = Radiobutton(window,text='3d Scatter', value=2, variable=selected)

rad3 = Radiobutton(window,text='Pie Chart', value=3, variable=selected)

rad4 = Radiobutton(window,text='Histogram', value=4, variable=selected)

def clicked():

   print("Processing")

btn = Button(window, text="Show", command=clicked)

rad1.grid(column=0, row=0)

rad2.grid(column=2, row=0)

rad3.grid(column=0, row=1)

rad4.grid(column=2, row=1)

btn.grid(column=6, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Embedding Bokeh server apps requires running JavaScript code. In order for a tkinter app to embed Bokeh content, it would have to have some method or widget for embedding HTML +JS, full stop. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53394551/3406693) seems to suggest that is possible, but you will just have to experiment (I have not used tkinter in 20 years, so I cannot comment any further). The Bokeh APIs for generating the JS embedding code are [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#bokeh-applications).

Comment: hi, and with pyqt? could it be possible?

Comment: I have heard of people having success with qt. I believe there are a couple of questions and answers here on SO that you could search for.

Comment: I've searched ... and you seem the most active

Comment: I don't use Qt (I don't do any rich-client GUI dev and have not for a very, very long time).  There is nothing I can add about Qt specifically, other than note the recollection that some people were successfull in embedding Bokeh in a Qt web widget at some point. FYI the Bokeh project only tests with actual browsers. It is "nice" if things work with rich-client GUI libraries, but to be clear, that is technically unsupported, "YMMV" territory.