# How to display mapbox in tkinter in python

Tags: python, tkinter, mapbox

```
    from tkinter import *                 
    import plotly.graph_objects as go
    root = Tk()   
    root.geometry("1300x700")
    mapbox_access_token ="pk.eyJ1Ijoidml2ZWtrdW1hcmxhbCIsImEiOiJjazdoZDI2enkwOTBiM21sbGpubnQwN3g4In0.ClK-bWxExBsMOcHoyvcrXg"
        
    fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
                lat=['45.5017'],
                lon=['-73.5673'],
                mode='markers',
                marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
                    size=14
                ),
                text=['Montreal'],
            ))
        
    fig.update_layout(
            hovermode='closest',
            mapbox=dict(
                accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
                bearing=0,
                center=go.layout.mapbox.Center(
                    lat=45,
                    lon=-73
                ),
                pitch=0,
                zoom=5
            )
        )
    fig.place(width=600, x=0, y=25)
    fig.show()
    mainloop()
```

I tried to display mapbox in tkinter but getting errors.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-3312bf82150d> in <module>
     28         )
     29     )
---> 30 fig.place(width=600, x=0, y=25)
     31 fig.show()
     32 mainloop()

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'place'
```

The code without tkinter is running perfect on jupyter notebook. but want to know how to display it in tkinter.

Comment: "but getting errors" is too vague, please include the error messages in the question.

Comment: @j_4321 -- I have edited the question with error message please check.

Comment: You are getting this error because your `fig` object has no `place()` method, this is not a tkinter widget. According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426263/plotly-chart-at-tkinter-python, I don't think it is possible to embed a plotly graph in a tkinter window (while it is possiblle in a jupyter notebook).

Comment: @j_4321 Is there any alternative for showing mapbox in tkinter, any solution will be welcome.

Comment: I don't know anything about plotly or mapbox. What is possible for sure is to display a static map as an image in tkinter.