# add go.Figure graph into specific frame in tkiner

Tags: python, tkinter

I just want to add this graph created by go.Figure() into a specific frame. Followed is my code. I am getting this error.
AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'

I just want to add this figure into graph_frame as mentioned in the code followed.

```
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,NavigationToolbar2Tk
top = tk.Tk()   
top.title("NASDAR Stock price range prediction system")
top.geometry("1350x840")

#root = tk.Tk()
#main_frame = tk.Frame(root, height=600, width=1200)
graph_frame = tk.Frame(top, height=550, width=700)
graph_frame.place(x=365,y=185) 
special_graph = Button(top, text='Special Graph', command=(lambda : special_graph()))
special_graph.place(x = 860, y = 800)

def special_graph():
    
    data1 = yf.download('BA', period='365d', interval='1d')
    
    #print(data1.tail(25))
    df = data1.copy()
    df['EMA8'] = 0
    df['EMA21'] = 0
    df['SMA200'] = 0    
    #calculate various EMA

    df['EMA8'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=8, adjust=False).mean()
    df['EMA21'] = df['Close'].ewm(span=21, adjust=False).mean()
    df['SMA200'] = df['Close'].rolling(200).mean()    
    df = df[['Close', 'SMA200', 'EMA8', 'EMA21']]    

    df.columns = ['Close','y', 'ma1', 'ma2']

    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    df = df.tail(30)
    df1 = df.copy()
    #print(df1.tail(25))
    # split data into chunks where averages cross each other
    df['label'] = np.where(df['ma1']>df['ma2'], 1, 0)
    df['group'] = df['label'].ne(df['label'].shift()).cumsum()
    df = df.groupby('group')
    dfs = []
    for name, data in df:
        dfs.append(data)
    #print(dfs)
    # custom function to set fill color
    def fillcol(label):
        if label >= 1:
            return 'rgba(0,250,0,0.4)'
        else:
            return 'rgba(250,0,0,0.4)'

    fig = go.Figure()
    
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, graph_frame)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)

    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    for df in dfs:
        fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y = df.ma1,
                                  line = dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)')))

        fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y = df.ma2,
                                  line = dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)'),
                                  fill='tonexty', 
                                  fillcolor = fillcol(df['label'].iloc[0])))

    # include averages
    fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df1.index, y = df1.ma1,
                              line = dict(color = 'blue', width=0.5)))

    fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df1.index, y = df1.ma2,
                              line = dict(color = 'red', width=0.5)))

    # include main time-series
    fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df1.index, y = df1.y,
                              line = dict(color = 'blue',width=1)))
    fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=df1.index, y = df1.Close,
                              line = dict(color = 'black', width=0.75)))
    fig.update_layout(xaxis_rangeslider_visible = True)

    fig.update_layout(showlegend=False)

  
top.mainloop()
```

followed is the detailed error.

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'set_canvas'

Comment: `plotly` generate plot as `HTML` and `tkinter` doesn't have method to display `HTML`. And `go.Figure()` is NOT figure which needs tkinter. `matplot` and `plotly` are two different worlds and they may not work together. Probably to display `plotly` you would have to use `cef` for `Chrome Embed Framwork` which uses browser Chrome.

Comment: page [Plotly Chart at Tkinter Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426263/plotly-chart-at-tkinter-python) explains it - there is also link to [Is it possible to render HTML in Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46571448/is-it-possible-to-render-html-in-tkinter?noredirect=1&lq=1) which shows how to use [cef](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython) in Python.

Comment: I am able to achieve what  I needed using followed. #ax.fill_between(df['Date'], df['EMA8']-df['EMA21']) # it gives color gap at bottom of graph
    ax.fill_between(df['Time'], df['EMA8'], df['EMA21'], where=(df['EMA8'] > df['EMA21']), color = 'lightgreen')
    ax.fill_between(df['Time'], df['EMA8'], df['EMA21'], where=(df['EMA8'] < df['EMA21']), color = 'tomato')