# Integrate Plotly express with PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, plotly-express

I am new to PySimpleGUI and have to represent a Funell in a page. By what I have learned from the internet, Matplotlib should work but is complicated. But plotly express has a direct function to create funnels, and as hard as I have tried, I have not found a way to copy the plotly graph to PySimpleGUI. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426263/plotly-chart-at-tkinter-python